# React use different imported Component based on a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am aware that this is not the best approach to do this, but still, for now I have to solve as the following:

> Failed to compile, Unexpected token if

```
<Col>
{
  if (language === 'en')
  {
    Api.getFaqText().map(b => {
      if (b.id === 1)
        return <BHead textClass={b.classname} key={b.id} title={(<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: b.title}} />)} />
    })
  }
}
</Col>
```

The question is how to decide which imported Modules functions to use, in a condition. The `Api.getFaqText` is coming from an `import Api from 'path/'` and then there's gonna be an `import Y from 'path/'` which also have a function called `getFaqText`.

How to modify this piece if condition, to avoid the render to break?

The example provided in the gist below is not working, because I am getting an unexpected token in the `if`.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/zilahir/0a7e4af0d00a067c5667110a035b5e4b

Answer (score 1):

1) Use a `Condition && <Component />` construct to implement your condition

2) In your map function, return `null` instead of nothing. Otherwise you could user filter before map.

```
  render() {
    return <Col>
      {language === 'en' && Api.getFaqText().map(b => {
          if (b.id === 1) {
             return <BHead textClass={b.classname} key={b.id} title={(<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: b.title}} />)} />;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        })
      }
    </Col>
  }
```